# Validating quartz's JobDataMap

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Jobs in Quartz are passed a JobDataMap for the arguments that it may need. Obviously this introduces potential for the data to be the wrong types, wrong data values etc.

Some ideas:

- Each job has a `Config` class that behaves a bit like a ViewModel in that it has all the data the job needs contained in it. This could then use DataAnnotations for the validation.
- Extending the IJob class and creating custom objects which internally validates (seems like too much work)

How is validation normally asserted on JobDataMaps?

Comment: Instead of the `JobDataMap` i would recommend that you use an JobFactory and inject all dependencies.

Comment: Interesting, I think that may be the best option!